# Google App Engine DEFAULT_ENCODING fails in local environment Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, utf-8, intellij-idea

Following Instructions detailed here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#System_Properties_and_Environment_Variables
To set the Default Encoding to UTF-8 like so:

```
<env-variables>
  <env-var name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
</env-variables>
```

Throws the following exception:

> com.google.appengine.tools.development.EnvironmentVariableChecker$IncorrectEnvironmentVariableException:
>   One or more environment variables have been configured in
>   appengine-web.xml that have missing or different values in your local
>   environment. We recommend you use system properties instead, but if
>   you are interacting with legacy code that requires specific
>   environment variables to have specific values, please set these
>   environment variables in your environment before running. [Mismatch
>   environmentVariableName=DEFAULT_ENCODING environmentVariableValue=null
>   appEngineWebXmlValue=UTF-8
>   appEngineWebXmlFile=C:\xxx\out\artifacts\yyy_war_exploded\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml]
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.EnvironmentVariableChecker.check(EnvironmentVariableChecker.java:75)

I have tried this:

```
-DDEFAULT_ENCODING=UTF-8
```

And this:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

On the server launch configuration and

```
JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -DDEFAULT_ENCODING=UTF-8
```

I'm using Windows 8 pro and Intellij Ultimate

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Solved it by creating the following Enviroment Variable:
DEFAULT_ENCODING=UTF-8

The part:

```
<env-variables>
  <env-var name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
</env-variables>
```

is not needed in your appengine-web.xml

Bonus help in case it is needed:
https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: How then you'll run it on the production server?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Mac, and running the following line:

```
export DEFAULT_ENCODING="UTF-8"
```

before starting the local server fixed it.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what the equivalent command in Windows is.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Environment variables can be set from:

Control Panel->All Control Panel Items->System->Environment Variables

Variable: DEFAULT_ENCODING
Value: UTF-8

You will need to restart your IDE after setting the value.